# Como conectar moongose a un mongodb en la nube?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

He visto que esta es la conexión que se necesita:

```js
//Full Driver Example
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://dbUser594:<password>@cluster0-ryb4p.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

Sin embargo yo lo tengo conectado en mi PC usando moongose:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const routes = require('./routes/api')

// Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/muntraingo', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', routes)

// middleware para admitir errores:
app.use((err,req,res, next) => {
    res.status(422).send({
        error: err.message
    })
})
app.listen(process.env.port || 4000, () => console.log('express listening now...'))
```

¿Que es lo que tengo que cambiar?

En las opciones del Cluster para conectarlo, también he probado a conectarlo con la aplicación de escritorio "MongoDb Compass". Se conecta perfectamente pero la base de datos que me interesa (`muntraingo`) se crea en localhost27017, y no en esa conexión. Que debo cambiar en el código para que la base de datos se almacene aquí en vez de a mi Pc local?:

```
mongodb+srv://dbUser594:<password>@cluster0-ryb4p.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes sustituir de esta manera la conexión que tienes actualmente:

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const routes = require('./routes/api')


    //Esta parte es la que tienes que cambiar
    // Connect to mongodb
    //mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/muntraingo', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    //Hasta aqui ------------------------

    //Con esto:

   const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   const uri = "mongodb+srv://dbUser594:<password>@cluster0-ryb4p.mongodb.net/admin? 
   retryWrites=true&w=majority";
   const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
   client.connect(err => {
       const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
      // perform actions on the collection object
      client.close();
  });

    ///Fin de sustitucion -------------

     mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    app.use(express.static('public'))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use('/api', routes)

    // middleware para admitir errores:
    app.use((err,req,res, next) => {
        res.status(422).send({
            error: err.message
        })
    })
    app.listen(process.env.port || 4000, () => console.log('express listening now...'))
```

No olvides remplazar `<password>` con tu contraseña.

Comment: Me sale este error al poner tu código: "MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db" ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Posiblemente este cerrándose la conexión.  Intenta quitando la linea `client.close()`

Comment: Tambien son interesantes estos comentarios: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768876/mongoclient-must-be-connected-before-calling-mongoclient-prototype-db-on-heroku?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: voy a echarle un ojo más en profundidad. Aunque tengo puesto el cluster para que sea accesible desde cualquier IP asi que no debería ser problema de eso.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. El error era tan simple que me da hasta vergüenza: estaba poniendo la password conversvando los "<"">" como así "<mipassword>" en vez de "mipassword"

Comment: @JavierCake jajaja, te entiendo, me pasa todo el tiempo...